# Adding ArcGIS Online hosted layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer

Looking for information on if it is possible to add hosted feature layers from ArcGIS Online to a QGIS project and if it is then possible to add the hosted feature layer if the sharing is set to our organisation on ArcGIS Online.

I have seen post about being able to add WMS from ArcGIS online so I am hoping hosted feature layers are the same.

The reason for the need is that we have started working with a new team who only want to use QGIS.

Comment: Like https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/

Comment: Hi this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link shows how to connect QGIS to the ArcGIS Online.

https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).